# How to use input string as variable call in python?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I am a beginner python learner. I was wondering if it was possible to create a basic massage encrypting system without using any modules. I want my programm to check and use variable name that is in string.

let's say,

```
a = 'l'
b = '5'
c = 'o'

x = input("Enter your massage: ")

print(x, 'THE_USER INPUT matching the variable name and values')
```

I know I can do this with while or if, but it would take forever. Also, how do you separate each string letters before you match the variable.

I am using python 3. Thanks :)

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: I was equally confused when I wrote this, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this is what you are trying to do, but here goes:

```
a = 'l'
b = '5'
c = 'o'

x = input("Enter your message: ")
values = [globals().get(var, '') for var in list(x)]

print "".join(values)
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
Enter your message: abc
l5o
```

A more appropriate way to do this would likely be:

```
replacements = { 'a': 'l', 'b': '5', 'c': 'o' }

x = input("Enter your message: ")
print "".join([replacements.get(val, "") for val in x])
```

Comment: on a side note while this is what the OP asked for this is probably not really what they should be doing...

Comment: Completely and totally agree.

Comment: your more appropriate way is a significant improvement. .. but really he should be using string.translate for this ...

Comment: Thanks This is exactly what I was looking for. I will now have to check out references to understand the new syntax. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

use string.translate  this is a much more correct way to do what it sounds like you want

```
from string import maketrans

in_tab  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
out_tab = "5QR&*(=-;Wwz%$^#@!yY~:123xq"

t = maketrans(in_tab,out_tab)
print ("Hello World".translate(t))
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted to do, but i don't want any help from any modules. Thanks, I didn't know I could do that. I will use this methods in future :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you meant substituting every occurrence of a given character by another one, have a look at the [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) function.

You could extend your example code as follows:

```
import string

in = input("Enter your message: ")
mapping = string.maketrans('abc', '15o')
out = in.translate(mapping)
print(out)
```

Every `a` is substituted by a `1`, every `b` by `5`, every `c` by `o`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a method that works without importing any module. I think this requires module. But it seems easier and I will use it later on :)

Comment: You are right, added the missing import. But using modules is nothing to avoid! Do not try to reinvent the wheel :) Especially not for such common and tedious/error-prone tasks as string manipulation.

Comment: BTW: The import is just necessary for the `maketrans` helper function, it just builds a 256 character-long string for you that you **could** specify yourself. Not that anybody would want to do that.